# Javascript cannot identify 2 different PDF files

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I have two PDF files. If I select the second PDF (kfz) to print, the first PDF (bike) ends up printing anyway. Why is this? There are two different paths.

```
<script>
        function printTrigger(elementId) {
            var getMyFrame = document.getElementById(elementId);
            getMyFrame.focus();
            getMyFrame.contentWindow.print();
        }

    </script>

<tr>
                    <td>
                        Fahrrad Kaufvertrag 
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= Html.ActionLink("Download", "DownloadBikeContract", new { id = 1 }, new { @class = "SaveContract" })%>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <img src="../../Styles/Images/Buttons/printer.png" onclick="printTrigger('iFramePdf');" />
                    <iframe id="iFramePdf" src="../../Files/KaufvertragFahrrad.pdf" style="display: none;">
                    </iframe>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    KFZ - Kaufvertrag
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%= Html.ActionLink("Download", "DownloadKFZContract", new { id = 2 }, new { @class = "SaveContract" })%>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img src="../../Styles/Images/Buttons/printer.png" onclick="printTrigger('iFramePdf');" />
                    <iframe id="iFrame1" src="../../Files/KaufvertragKFZ.pdf" style="display: none;">
                    </iframe>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second image says `onclick="printTrigger('iFramePdf');"`, but the ID of the second iframe is `iFrame1`, not `iFramePdf`.  You just need to pass the right string to your `printTrigger()` call.

Comment: it was easier as i thought :)